# TranformClassesWtihDexForDebug error with Jackson and Realm libraries

Tags: android, jackson, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I trying to compile my project using the Jackson json parser and Square's Realm db libraries for Android. I get the following error when compiling using `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktace`

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.Exe
cException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:421)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe''
finished with non-zero exit value 2
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.dexOutOfProcess(AndroidBuilder.java:1553)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.runDexer(AndroidBuilder.java:1495)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1482)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:406)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.dexOutOfProcess(AndroidBuilder.java:1549)
        ... 83 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$3.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1538)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$3.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1531)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
        ... 2 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 36.117 secs
```

My build.gradle files:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.3'
    ext.build_tools_version = '23.0.1'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects { project ->
    if(project.name.endsWith("-schema")) {
        apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'
        dependencies {
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7'
        }
    }
}
```

app module gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    productFlavors {
        instantrunconfig {
            applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.0'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.0'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.0']
    )
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile group: 'com.google.transit', name: 'gtfs-realtime-bindings', version: '0.0.4'

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$build_tools_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$build_tools_version"
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2-b01'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1' // EDIT
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}
```

I updated the JDK to the latest version and explicitly referenced in my gradle.properties file. My gradle scripts are rather basic so I think I am missing something small - any ideas?

EDIT -----

I added the React java libraries but now I am getting

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForInstantrunconfigDebug'.
> class com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

I updated the gradle file here to reflect the changes. I commented out the dex options but I am still getting the same error.

EDIT2 -------

I disabled instant and now I am getting

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
> class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the backtrace looks a bit different, I think it should be same problem caused by reflection on Realm's RxJava related APIs.

Please check doc [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind) to see how to solve it.

Comment: Any idea why the stack trace is such garble though?

Comment: No idea ... a windows problem maybe?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Disable Instant Run

2.) Don't add `rxjava` just because you want to avoid this error, [you should create `rx` package in your code and add an empty class called `Observable`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind)

```
package rx;

public class Observable {
}
```